# Form Data is correct when POSTing in Angular, but req.body is empty in node?

Tags: node.js, forms, angularjs, post, express

I am trying to do a simple POST call to a RESTful API that I created.  I am using Angular for the client-side, nodejs for the server, and mongodb+express+[multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for the database.

When testing the back-end using [POSTman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), the objects are created correctly, getting data from the req.body.  In my Angular controller's createProject method, I am printing out my formData right before POSTing to the API.  The form data looks correct.  When the correct form data is POSTed to the working server, the req.body shows up empty.

Here is my relevant server code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(multer({ dest: 'public/uploads/'}));

router.route('/projects')  // accessed at //localhost:8080/api/projects

.post(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // returns empty set
    var project = new Project();

    project.name = req.body.name;
    project.description = req.body.description;
    project.newComments = 0;
    project.newPosts = 0;
    //project.imageURL = req.body.imageURL;

    project.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        Project.find(function(err, projects) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            res.json(projects);
        });
    });
})

app.use('/api', router);
```

Here is my relevant Angular code:

```
$scope.createProject = function() {
    console.log($scope.formData); // returns correct **{name: "adawda", description: "dawdaw"} **
    $http.post('/api/projects', $scope.formData)
        .success(function(projectData) {
            $scope.formData = {};
            $scope.imageURL = "";
            $scope.projects = projectData;
            console.log(projectData);
        })
        .error(function(projectData) {
            console.log('Error: ' + projectData);
        });
};
```

Here is my relevant HTML code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name of project" ng-model="formData.name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="description" ng-model="formData.description" />
<button type="submit" class="button" ng-click="createProject()">Create Project</button>
```

The Question:

How does Angular pass data from the $scope.formData to the request, and why is it not compatible with my server configuration?  I'm pretty sure it has to do with the content-type in my POST, and how that relates to multer.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have the [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware enabled? It's included with Express 3, but you'll need to install it yourself in Express 4. Its job is to extract the body of an incoming request (JSON, urlencoded, multipart) and parse it into a JavaScript object.

Comment: I'm using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for my middleware.  It can only handle multipart/form data.

Comment: Do you think I could use both?

Comment: You don't need to use the entire `body parser` middleware. You can just use its JSON or urlencoded parsers. You may not even need both.

Comment: Okay I got it working by adding the body parser middleware.  I was under the assumption that Multer would include the body parser middleware, but I guess it's meant to be used in conjunction.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use body parser middleware

app.use(bodyParser());

Comment: I am also facing same issue in nodejs even i am using the above line @Ravi Babu Karikati